# How to fit an image fully into HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I have this code of a sliding puzzle game.
When I use exactly 500x500 pixel image everything works fine but when I insert a large image, only the left upper corner of the image is visible and only this part is devided into 16 puzzle parts. How do I fit the whole image on the canvas?

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  .picture {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="title">
    <h2>Sliding Puzzle</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="slider">
    <form>
      <label>Easy</label>
      <input type="range" id="scale" value="4" min="3" max="5" step="1">
      <label>Hard</label>
    </form>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="main" class="main">
    <canvas id="puzzle" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script>
  var context = document.getElementById('puzzle').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.antilimit.com/nature/i/37.jpg';

img.addEventListener('load', drawTiles, false);

var boardSize = document.getElementById('puzzle').width;
var tileCount = 4

var tileSize = boardSize / tileCount;

var clickLoc = new Object;
clickLoc.x = 0;
clickLoc.y = 0;

var emptyLoc = new Object;
emptyLoc.x = 0;
emptyLoc.y = 0;

var solved = false;

var boardParts;
setBoard();

document.getElementById('scale').onchange = function() {
  tileCount = this.value;
  tileSize = boardSize / tileCount;
  setBoard();
  drawTiles();
};

document.getElementById('puzzle').onclick = function(e) {
  clickLoc.x = Math.floor((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / tileSize);
  clickLoc.y = Math.floor((e.pageY - this.offsetTop) / tileSize);
  if (distance(clickLoc.x, clickLoc.y, emptyLoc.x, emptyLoc.y) == 1) {
    slideTile(emptyLoc, clickLoc);
    drawTiles();
  }
  if (solved) {
    setTimeout(function() {alert("You solved it!");}, 500);
  }
};

function setBoard() {
  boardParts = new Array(tileCount);
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    boardParts[i] = new Array(tileCount);
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
      boardParts[i][j] = new Object;
      boardParts[i][j].x = (tileCount - 1) - i;
      boardParts[i][j].y = (tileCount - 1) - j;
    }
  }
  emptyLoc.x = boardParts[tileCount - 1][tileCount - 1].x;
  emptyLoc.y = boardParts[tileCount - 1][tileCount - 1].y;
  solved = false;
}

function drawTiles() {
  context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , boardSize , boardSize );
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
      var x = boardParts[i][j].x;
      var y = boardParts[i][j].y;
      if(i != emptyLoc.x || j != emptyLoc.y || solved == true) {
        context.drawImage(img, x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize,
            i * tileSize, j * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
      }
    }
  }
}

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return Math.abs(x1 - x2) + Math.abs(y1 - y2);
}

function slideTile(toLoc, fromLoc) {
  if (!solved) {
    boardParts[toLoc.x][toLoc.y].x = boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].x;
    boardParts[toLoc.x][toLoc.y].y = boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].y;
    boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].x = tileCount - 1;
    boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].y = tileCount - 1;
    toLoc.x = fromLoc.x;
    toLoc.y = fromLoc.y;
    checkSolved();
  }
}

function checkSolved() {
  var flag = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
      if (boardParts[i][j].x != i || boardParts[i][j].y != j) {
        flag = false;
      }
    }
  }
  solved = flag;
}

  </script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: First decide with which ratio the image need to re-scale (declare variable `ratio`), then change your image drawing line of code to `context.drawImage(img, x * tileSize / ratio, y * tileSize / ratio, tileSize / ratio, tileSize / ratio, i * tileSize, j * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);`

Answer (score 1):

The image you are using in your example is 1000px by 1000px, so dividing this into sixteen tiles requires each the image to be split into sixteen sections where each section will be 250px by 250px. Currently you are using sixteen sections each of which is 125px by 125px and so your are only copying the top left quarter of the image.

Take a rectangular image of width  W and height H, then starting at the top left corner you can take a square image of imgSize = W if W<=H or of imgSize = H if H

You find the scaling factor imgScale = imgSize/500

In your example imgSize = 1000 and so imgScale = 2 so you want to copy sections twice the width and height of the tiles

Change the drawTiles function to

```
function drawTiles() {
  var imgSize=Math.min(img.width,img.height);
  var imgScale=imgSize/500;     
  context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , boardSize , boardSize );
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
      var x = boardParts[i][j].x;
      var y = boardParts[i][j].y;
      if(i != emptyLoc.x || j != emptyLoc.y || solved == true) {
        context.drawImage(img, x * tileSize*imgScale, y * tileSize*imgScale, tileSize*imgScale, tileSize*imgScale,
            i * tileSize, j * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v2orn44/1/)